# Preventing automatic website refresh/redirects in Firefox 56

Tags: firefox

I am using Firefox 56 and in versions prior to 56 there was an option under `Options > Advanced` called “Warn you when websites try to redirect or reload the page,” which blocked automatic website refreshes and redirects when selected. It showed a warning and a button to manually allow the refresh/redirect at the top of the webpage. I’ve had this option enabled for years.

Now that Firefox has “reorganized” the `Options` interface as of version 56, this option is no longer present and indeed the browser refreshes and redirections occur automatically once again.

How would one prevent automatic website refresh/redirects in Firefox 56?

Answer (score 1):

In `about:config`, set `accessibility.blockautorefresh` to `true`.

References:

1. I typed "refresh" into `about:config` to see what could come up
2. http://kb.mozillazine.org/Accessibility.blockautorefresh

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  The link reflects Firefox V3, which is pretty ancient, and the page was last updated 6 years ago.  You indicate you found the setting by searching your own about:config.  The question is based on the structure having changed in V56.  Can you edit your answer to add your version number, which will confirm that it applies?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A few updates later, in Firefox 64.0.2, I did something similar to MinebeaMitsumi's approach, and it worked.
Address bar: go to `about:config`
Search for `accessibility.blockautorefresh`
For me, `accessibility.blockautorefresh` was set to `true` by default.
 I set it to **false**.
Now URLs for which Firefox would have previously popped up a "Firefox prevented this link from automatically redirecting to another page" message at the top now redirect without asking.

Comment: This is opposite to the action Mozilla describes for this setting.